# A sectionwise fiber sequence is homotopy fiber sequence?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories, simplicial-presheaves

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a site and $\mathsf{sPre}(\mathscr{C})$ the category of simplicial presheaves on $\mathscr{C}$ equipped with Jardine's local model structure. Let $E\to B$ is a sectionwise Kan fibration and $F\to E\to B$ a sectionwise fiber sequence of simplicial presheaves on $\mathscr{C}$ (i.e. for every $U\in\mathscr{C}$, $F(U)\to E(U)\to B(U)$ is a homotopy fiber sequence of simplicial sets). Then is $F\to E\to B$ always a homotopy fiber sequence in $\mathsf{sPre}(\mathscr{C})$ (with respect to Jardine's local model structure)? This is asking whether the map from $F$ to the homotopy fiber of $E\to B$ is a local weak equivalence.

Comment: I am trying to understand some of these same notions: wouldn't a counterexample be provided by any sectionwise fibration that is not a global fibration? So say something that is sectionwise fibrant but not globally fibrant?